# Is using the new System.Tuple class bad design?

Tags: .net, patterns-and-practices

I like the concept of System.Tuple in that it allows me to return multiple parameters in a single function call without instantiating a new class, however does this defy any good programming practices such as Microsoft Patterns & Practices, SOLID Principles, etc.

I'm just trying to gauge how liberally I should use this feature or if I should only use it in edge case scenarios when necessary.

Comment: +1: Excellent question. Also - I wonder if Anders Hejlsberg has weighed in on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue with using `Tuple` is that the generic type parameters do not convey meaning.

For readability you may want to consider using a custom class or even an anonymous type with named members.

Comment: What about the XML parameter description? Not the most obvious place to look, but better than nothing.

Comment: @SkippyFire - How do you mean? All you get is the type of `T1`, `T2` etc. Doesn't tell you what they mean.

Comment: I have to say: every time I (or someone on our team) has used a Tuple as a type, I am constantly referring back to other parts in the code to remember what .Item1, .Item2, etc. are.  For anything that is not completely trivial, create discrete classes.  Give yourself a chance in the future to know what it is you were doing.

Comment: @Oded I'm talking about *adding* XML documentation to a method accepting a Tuple.  Again, not perfect, but better than nothing if you want/need to use Tuples.

Comment: @Oded Also, the parameter or return value may not convey meaning, but the name of the method can.  Let's say you have a method called `GetTopTwoPercentages()` that returns a `Tuple<decimal, decimal>`.  That might be clear enough.

Answer (score 12):

One of the most important code qualities is readability. So ask yourself:
When I (i.e. in anybody else but you) look at the method signature, do I know what meaning the respective components of the `Tuple` have?
For example if the pair of floats you are returning is a set of polar coordinates, is this clear?

This is clear:

```
Tuple<Float, Float> getPolarCoords();
```

This is misleading (because one would assume Cartesian coordinates):

```
Tuple<Float, Float> getCoords();
```

And this is devoid meaning:

```
Tuple<Float, Float> getTuple();
```

So generally speaking, you will have evaluate clarity on a per-case basis and refactor if necessary. If you represent the same kind of data as `Tuple` in many different places, then creating a class is definitely a good idea.